# Windows 7 reinstall now boot is broken

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I had a virus on the Windows 7 part of my pc. I had to format the drive using the ubuntu side. then reinstalled fresh on the w7 part. originally, it only booted to w7 and then I have been trying to update and fix the mbr. here is the result. i get the choices at startup(as before) but it is not pointed in the correct direction(i think) because i get dos style text when i choose ubuntu and just fails.
help appreciated.thanks

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11942370/

Comment: You have grub installed to MBR, do you get grub menu? You have a lot of kernels & need to houseclean most to clean up grub menu. If you get grub menu, does Windows boot from it? Then how is Ubuntu failing? Remove splash quiet from linux line in boot stanza with e for edit on Ubuntu entry in grub. What video card/chip?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Insert` the Ubuntu `LiveUSB` and `reboot` the computer.

The machine `boots` from the `LiveUSB`.

Click the `Try Ubuntu Without Installing` icon from the LiveUSB `Start` menu. Ubuntu boots from the LiveUSB.

Click `Applications` from the top taskbar in the Ubuntu desktop, and then click `Accessories`.

Click the `Terminal` option. The Ubuntu command-line terminal opens.

Type the following command at the prompt and press the `Enter` key.

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sda5
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: Boot-Repair effectively runs the chroot with a total uninstall or reinstall of grub. But in most cases you can just mount Linux partition and install grub to MBR. This full chroot is last of the alternatives when having boot issues and a full chroot can be useful for other major repairs.